# Telethon: Telegram is having internal issues NeedChatInvalidError: The provided chat is invalid (caused by EditChatPhotoRequest)

Tags: python, telethon

```
Telethon: Telegram is having internal issues NeedChatInvalidError: The provided chat is invalid (caused by EditChatPhotoRequest)
```

I getting that error when I trying to change chat photo. Chat ID is correct, I checked it and tried with others.

```
await client(EditChatPhotoRequest(chat_id=-1001849699571,
                                  photo=await client.upload_file('noname.png')))
```

Answer (score 1):

-100 prefix is only for Channels. Not Chats. (plus, a Chat request doesn't take peers, so, telethon won't resolve it for you, hence -100 prefix or negative is rendered useless.)

you pass id as is:

```
client(EditChatPhotoRequest(chat_id=1849699571, ...))
```